# Android Sharing webview in viewpager fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, android-viewpager

I have Viewpager which is currently loading new fragments.  Each fragment has a web view which we load a url with.

the website is basically the same site but we change its state by calling some javascript when the fragment is created.

the problem is we don't want to load the website every time the fragment is created - we want to carry over the web session, or state of the web view because the server can only handle a single session and would otherwise lose session data

So we don't want to reload the url in the fragment create method.  Is their a way to share the web view and its current state across fragments in a view pager ?  i.e perhaps store the web view instance globally in the app and reference in each fragment ?  or something like that